# No type error when passing a super class object via a sub class argument in Dart

Tags: inheritance, types, dart, arguments

I'm curious as to why Dart doesn't flag a super class as being an incorrect type when it's passed in via an inherited type argument? Taking the inherited type as the parameter means the inherited type's interface should expect to be utilised, which the super class might not have. This seems like a bug?

Exemplified below:

```dart
class ClassTest {
  int i;
}

void a(Object x) {
  b(x); // ClassTest inherits Object, but that doesn't mean it has the same interface
}

void b(ClassTest x){
  x.i = 2; // a() can pass a non type safe class to make this fail
}
```

This brings up no errors in the editor for me. I'd at least expect a warning for 'x' to be cast `as ClassTest` before being passed? I'm not sure if this is normal behaviour, but I have come across it quite a bit.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. See [this answer from Bob Nystrom, engineer on the Dart team](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/wsIRErzte_o/tk1epKbvbkwJ):

> Dart is different here. It has something called "assignment compatibility" to determine which assignments are valid. Most languages just use the normal subtyping rules for this: an assignment is safe if you assign from a sub- to a supertype. Dart's assignment compatibility rules also allow assigning from a super- to a subtype.
>
> In other words, you can downcast implicitly in an assignment, without needing any kind of explicit cast. So there's no static warning here. However, if you run the code in checked mode and that downcast turns out to be invalid (as it is here), you will get a type error at runtime when you try to assign a double to x.

Comment: Oh right, so this "feature" can trade a potential IDE error for a potential runtime error? So by offloading this as something that is validated as part of the language, I take the IDE is now going to try and do type inference in future iterations to try and make this safer? Since Dart is optionally typed, and I can't explicitly set a type in this instance (as Object is the main super class), I'd love to have the option to see potential type errors flagged without me having write `if (x is ClassTest)` or carry out reflection. Does anyone know if this is in the future for Dart?

Comment: I'm not aware of such an option. Feel free to [file an issue](http://dartbug.com).

Comment: This is just awful.  Either strict rules or structural subtype (duck type) would at least give you options for dealing with this but Dart just seems to leave this as a huge hole in the type system.