# How to overcome List Subtype inference problem when trying to add a Superclass object to the List?

Tags: list, flutter, generics, dart

In a Flutter app I have a `Row` of `Column`s widget hierarchy. However I'd like to add an extra `SizedBox` into every alternating column of widgets.

```
  Column getColumn(List<DAO> column, int index, BoardLayout layout) {
    final key = column.map((c) => c.toString()).toList().join('_');
    final items = column.map((c) => MyWidget(data: c)).toList();
    if (index % 2 == 0 && layout == BoardLayout.Hexagonal)
      items.add(SizedBox(height: magicNumber));
    return Column(children: items);
  }
```

This yields a compile time error of `"The argument type 'SizedBox' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyWidget'."`. That's understandable, because `final items` must have gotten the inferred type `List<MyWidget>` and then I wanted to add a `SizedBox`. All of these have the supertype of `Widget` though. If I modify this as:

```
  Column getColumn(List<DAO> column, int index, BoardLayout layout) {
    final key = column.map((c) => c.toString()).toList().join('_');
    List<Widget> items = column.map((c) => MyWidget(data: c)).toList();
    if (index % 2 == 0 && layout == BoardLayout.Hexagonal)
      items.add(SizedBox(height: magicNumber));
    return Column(children: items);
  }
```

It compiles, but then it throws a runtime exception of `_TypeError` `"type 'SizedBox' is not a subtype of type 'MyWidget' of 'value'"`. I haven't found a way to force cast the list yet. I tried List's `cast<T>`, and trying explicit `(Widget)` or `(List<Widget>)` casting prefixes but none of my tries compiled yet. What's a possible solution for this? Details of `MyWidget` or `DAO` doesn't matter, I want the list to be a superclass type so I can add various types of Widgets to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `column.map`, Dart infers the type based on what the inner function returns. In this case, it returns a `MyWidget`, so even though Dart's type system allows you to declare `items` as a `List<Widget>`, it is actually a `List<MyWidget>`. (This ambiguity is supposedly getting removed in an upcoming version of Dart.)

To fix this, you need to add a type parameter to `map` to explicitly state what kind of list you want it to return:

```dart
List<Widget> items = column.map<Widget>((c) => MyWidget(data: c)).toList();
```

And on another note, casting in Dart is done using the `as` keyword. So for example, if you wanted to fix this using casting, it would look like this:

```dart
List<Widget> items = column.map((c) => MyWidget(data: c) as Widget).toList();
```

But the type parameter on `map` is the cleaner approach in my opinion.

---

The reason this is a problem is that unlike most programming languages, [Dart allows the assignment of supertype values to subtype variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31104110/1255873). This essentially means that if you assign a supertype value to a subtype variable, the compilation will allow it even though the runtime will not.

Take the following for example:

```dart
int a = 2.5; // Compilation error: double is not int
```

This code will obviously throw an error because a `double` is not an `int`. However, if you change it to the following:

```dart
int a = 2.5 as num; // Linter warning: unnecessary cast
```

The only notification we get on this code in the IDE is that casting a `double` to a `num` is unnecessary, but this is now shadowing a pretty grave error. Like before, we are trying to assign a `double` value to an `int` variable, but because of the cast, all the compiler sees is that we are trying to assign a `num` to an `int`. In most strongly-typed languages this would still result in a compile error since even though all `int`s are `num`s, not all `num`s are `int`s, so the compatibility between the value and the variable is not guaranteed. Dart, however, decides to allow the assignment anyway in the compilation, and it's not until the program runs that it throws the type mismatch error.

I can't for the life of me come up with a reason why the Dart engineers designed the language this way, since the only practical result of this I can see would be to change an easy-to-spot compilation error into a potentially elusive runtime error. The only possible justification I can come up with is that it's for interoperability with JavaScript (which Dart was originally developed for) and is an artifact of Dart's younger days as a weakly-typed language. This is a pretty major design flaw, and as I said before, I believe that a future version of Dart will remove this "feature" (though I cannot find the page I read that said so, so I hope I'm not just smoking something).

Comment: Gotcha, that worked. I browsed Dart docs and tried to do the same with `(Widget)` prefix casting, but that didn't compile. Your solution works, although the linter considers the `as Widget` cast as unnecessary. Apparently in this case it's necessary.

Comment: @CsabaToth The linter is wrong in this case, yeah. Generally casting is unnecessary in a lambda function since the return type of the lambda is pretty unambiguous, but that doesn't really help when you are trying to actually change the return type of the lambda for the benefit of whatever is calling it. That's why I prefer the type parameter option - you are explicitly setting the return type rather than trying to trick Dart's type inference system.

Comment: What I don't 100% get is if I explicitly tell Dart that my list is a `List<Widget>` then why it "overrides" that with a `List<MyWidget>`? Why explicit typing of the list varible is not enough in this case? I can mark the question as answer only later, SO has some time limits.

Comment: In this case it's a constructor, is there a type parameter option somewhere which is also a possible solution?

Comment: @CsabaToth I edited the answer with a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: @CsabaToth The type parameter solution is to give a type parameter to `map` which explicitly sets the resulting `List` type as I said in my answer. (There is no type parameter you can give to the constructor to change its return type, and there's no reason for it since that's what casting is for.)